# How to display MYSQL table columns in a CSS block style?

Tags: php, html

I want to display table columns in a css display:block style.The end result i want should look like the table below.

[image: block style]

I use MYSQL and PHP to display the columns of the table

This is how the data from the table currently looks like when it is rendered in the browser.

[image]

Source code

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("automobile")or die("Connection Failed");
$query = "select * from amin";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numcolumn = mysql_num_fields($result);
for ( $i = 0; $i < $numcolumn; $i++ ) {
 $columnnames = mysql_field_name($result, $i);

  echo "<table style ='width:100%'>";
  echo "<tr>";


  echo "<th>".$columnnames. "</th>";

  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Move the table and tr tags outside the loop.

Comment: You are creating a new table every time you have a new column name. Instead, make the table outside of the loop and make sure all column names are in the same tr (tr is a new row)

Comment: That was the problem @James and Blazemonger.I moved the table and tr tags outside the loop.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove table, tr open tag and closing tag from loop like below code. then you will expected ouput.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("automobile")or die("Connection Failed");
$query = "select * from amin";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numcolumn = mysql_num_fields($result);
   echo "<table style ='width:100%'>";
     echo "<tr>";
for ( $i = 0; $i < $numcolumn; $i++ ) {
     $columnnames = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
     echo "<th>".$columnnames. "</th>";         
 }

 echo "</tr>";
 echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Feces, you beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

Every instance the loop is running, it is creating a table with the width of 100% and pasting a header with the value of `$columnames` in to it. This means that since the loop is looking for if 0 is greater than the amount of columns (and adding one to it) that it will do this for every instance, and since the width is 100%, the "new table" created by the loop won't have space to fit in something like the side.

To solve this, use this code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("automobile")or die("Connection Failed");
$query = "select * from amin";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$numcolumn = mysql_num_fields($result);

  echo "<table style ='width:100%'>";
  echo "<tr>";

for ( $i = 0; $i < $numcolumn; $i++ ) {
 $columnnames = mysql_field_name($result, $i);

  echo "<th>".$columnnames. "</th>";

 }


  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
 ?>
```